# How to save binary data in MongoDB with NodeJS/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a buffer like this from the example below and I'd like to save its values in MongoDB in Decimal or Hexadecimal format.

Example:
My buffer is (Hexadecimal):

```
<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c >
```

I want to save like this in MongoDB:

```
72, 101, 108, 108
or Hexadecimal values: 48, 65, 6c, 6c
```

In my "arrayData" field the values saved are:

```
"arrayData" : [ { "0" : 72, "1" : 101, "2" : 108, "3" : 108 } ]
```

that is: It's creating objects...

My "arrayData" format in Mongoose is:

```
arrayData: { type: [] }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you not just want to do buff.toString("hex") and store the resulting string? How large are your binary files btw? mongo provides a nice thing called gridfs for handling large binaries.

Comment: Yes, sure. I can store the buffer directly in Hex format. Its length is about 150 bytes. But I don't want String HEX. I want Hexadecimal ou Decimal (whatever... binary). Unfortunately when saving the buffer It's happening which I pointed out above instead of saving the buffer as it is.

Comment: Sorry, the "buffer" field is correctly saving the information in the database (in binary). What I couldn't do is convert the Buffer to Array and then save correctly to the database.

Comment: Your type should be `Array` and not `[]`. 

Choose between `arrayData: []` and `arrayData: {type: Array}`

Comment: In fact, the two statements are equivalent and the two statements work. Check it out the documentation under "Mixed Types": https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: I want to save in the database a buffer `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c>` as an array, such `[48, 65, 6c, 6c]`